# Android Error "Application not installed"

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, manifest

I am using Droid X to test my application and it was working fine until I added several Activities to my application, the error says "Application not installed". I added few Activities that uses WebView, the code is below. I noticed that whenever I removed these Activities or remove just SOME of them, the app starts working again. I have added the following permissions below in my Manifest. It has been two days, and I can't still find the answer. I really need your help. I'm really guessing that the problems comes from too much Activities, but how can I handle it, I added everything that are need in my Manifest and still getting the same error over and over.

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test.cats"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />



    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name=".Activity1"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity3"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity4"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity5"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity6"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity7"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity8"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity9"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity10"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 


        <activity android:name=".Activity11"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity12"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity13"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity14"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity15"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity16"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity17"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity18"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity19"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 
        <activity android:name=".Activity20"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"/> 


    </application>
</manifest>
```

-
Here is my activity:

```
package com.test.cats;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Activity3 extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewlayout);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/video.html");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        callHiddenWebViewMethod("onPause");
        webView.pauseTimers();
        if(isFinishing()){
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
         }      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        callHiddenWebViewMethod("onResume");
        webView.resumeTimers();


    }

    private void callHiddenWebViewMethod(String name){

        if( webView != null ){
            try {
                Method method = WebView.class.getMethod(name);
                method.invoke(webView);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                //Lo.g("No such method: " + name + e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                //Lo.g("Illegal Access: " + name + e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                //Lo.g("Invocation Target Exception: " + name + e);

            }
        }
      }


    public void onBackPressed(){
        Activity2.this.finish();
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Paste the logs. Error message may give clues.

Comment: There's nothing in my Error Log.

Comment: You mean your [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat) is completely silent?

Comment: I'm not sure but, i use Eclipse, sometime logcat not show anything, i restart Eclipse. it works

Comment: Did you get any message in Console ?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you have declared an activity more than once in your manifest file. Remove `android:label="@string/app_name">` and try again. You have declared this twice. May be this is the reason its not working

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem can be here:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    Activity2.this.finish();
    return;
}
```

You try to call finish method for Activity2 although you work with Activity3.